# Is there a way to take any REST API and generate like WSDL document

Tags: rest, web-services, wsdl, wadl

I know that REST doesn't have WSDL document as SOAP has (some has WADL but not all, and it is not that common)
Is there a tool that take REST documentation (REST uri maybe) and generate describing document for that web service?

The tool swagger https://editor.swagger.io/ is able to do it only if added annotation to the source code of the web service not to any REST web service.

Comment: It is not necessary to add annotations on every REST controller or method to generate Swagger documentation. Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: @Justas you wrote that it is not necessary to add annotation, so how can I automatically create WSDL (swagger documentation, or others) file for REST service without these annotation?

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot: https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger-2/

Answer (score 0):

In short there is no official/REST approved way of doing what you are looking for.
WADL, Swagger and RAML are all "proposed" ways of achieving WSDL like functionality in REST, however they are proposed and not wildly supported by the development community.

If you were to start a new project these would make sense but if you want to run it on top of a existing project and generate some documentation you are pretty much out of luck.